# Why does lsl r3, r4, r5 result in r3 = AA000000 when r4=0x71AA0000 and r5 = 0x8?

Tags: arm

I thought 0x8 is hexadecimal, so one hex digit is equal to 4 bits. and in register r4, there are 32 bits, including the zeroes. Why do the first (left) bits fall off, instead of only 4?

The question is lsl r3, r4, r5, when r4=0x71AA0000 and r5 = 0x8, what is in r3?
the correct answer is supposed to be r3 = AA000000

Comment: 8 bits falling off would mean two times 4 bits falling off, in other words 2 hex digits fall off, which is what happened?

Comment: why does 0x8 count as 2 hex digits? its only 1 number

Comment: how does shifting has any relation to the number of hex digits? shifting by 8 is shifting by 8

Answer (score 0):

the question is unclear, but if you ask why, refer to [LSL in ARM Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/cb/Application-Level-Architecture/Instruction-Details/Alphabetical-list-of-instructions/LSL--register-)

as they said:

> **LSL Rd, Rn, Rm**
>
> Logical Shift Left (register) shifts a register value left by a variable number of bits, shifting in zeros, and writes the
> result to the destination register. The variable number of bits is read from the bottom byte of a register. It can
> optionally update the condition flags based on the result
>
> **Rd**: The destination register.
>
> **Rn**: The first operand register.
>
> **Rm**: The register whose bottom byte contains the amount to shift by.

so in your case, it means that it will do an **arithmetic shift left** the value stored in register **R4** by a number stored in register **R5** and put the result in register **R3**

so the value stored in Register **R4** in binary is :

```
0111 0001 1010 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

and so, be shifting left that binary number by `0x8` times which is `8` times.

so the result is :

```
1010 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

which in hex is `0xAA000000` and that value is stored in destination register which is **R3**

Comment: Correct, but 0x8 is hexadecimal. I thought 1 hex digit is equal to 4 bits. If the question asked r3, r4, #8 or r3, r4, #8 then I'd understand moving it by 8 bits, but its hex. I feel like I am missing some sort of understanding. My friend told me 0x8 counts as 8 x 16^0 which is the same as #8 in decimal

Comment: @Bigbootyfish, that's correct, every single Hexadecimal digit is 4 bits. but when shifting left you don't look at how many bits this number takes,  instead, you look at the number itself, its representation in decimal number to know how many times you will shift left. also, your friend is correct when he said  `0x8 counts as 8 x 16^0 which is the same as #8 in decimal`, the representation of **0x8** in binary is **1000** and the max value for a hexadecimal number is **0xA** which is **1111** in binary

Comment: Ok thanks. so if r5 = 0x9, i would shift r4 by 9 bits? and if it was 0x12 I would shift by 18 bits?

Comment: @Bigbootyfish, exactly

Answer (score 0):

Is this your confusion? And from comments I assume it is.

```
mov r5,#8
mov r5,#0x8
mov r5,#0x00000008

mov r5,#13
mov r5,#0xD
mov r5,#0x0000000D

mov r5,#17
mov r5,#0x11
mov r5,#0x00000011


so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
   4:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
   8:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
   c:   e3a0500d    mov r5, #13
  10:   e3a0500d    mov r5, #13
  14:   e3a0500d    mov r5, #13
  18:   e3a05011    mov r5, #17
  1c:   e3a05011    mov r5, #17
  20:   e3a05011    mov r5, #17
```

8 is 8

```
   0:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
   4:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
   8:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
```

13 is 13

```
   c:   e3a0500d    mov r5, #13
  10:   e3a0500d    mov r5, #13
  14:   e3a0500d    mov r5, #13
```

17 is 17

```
  18:   e3a05011    mov r5, #17
  1c:   e3a05011    mov r5, #17
  20:   e3a05011    mov r5, #17
```

How many minimum number of hex characters it takes to represent a number in a human readable form (or programming language) is not relevant to the shift.

It takes one hex character to hold the value 8 and 13.  But because that one nibble is 4 bits does not matter.  The register is 32 bits so it is 32 bits be it decimal 8, hex 0x8, octal 10, binary 1000, base 3 22 hex 0x0008, hex 0x000008, hex 0x000008, hex 0x00000008 and so on.

What you type into the programming language to get it to put some bits in a register is...just...what you type in the programming language to get it to put some bits in the register.  As shown above.

And, thank you, I did not ever try to do octal nor binary (base 2) in gnu assembler until this question...

```
mov r5,#8
mov r5,#0x8
mov r5,#0x08
mov r5,#0x0008
mov r5,#0x00008
mov r5,#0x000008
mov r5,#0x0000008
mov r5,#0x00000008
mov r5,#010
mov r5,#0010
mov r5,#00010
mov r5,#000010
mov r5,#0000010
mov r5,#0b1000
mov r5,#0b01000
mov r5,#0b001000
mov r5,#0b0001000
mov r5,#0b00001000
mov r5,#0b000001000
```

gives

```
   0:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
   4:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
   8:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
   c:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  10:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  14:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  18:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  1c:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  20:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  24:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  28:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  2c:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  30:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  34:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  38:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  3c:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  40:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  44:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
  48:   e3a05008    mov r5, #8
```

same machine code.  The text characters needed to represent the value we want in a 32 bit register...are the text characters, we happen to have choices with this particular tool.  like C language it appears a leading 0 without a b or x after it is octal, googling for nasm you can do 0o10 and 10q but not gnu assembler for arm.

And also note that say for example you are talking about a processor with an 18 bit register or address.  You can still represent that in hex 0x12345, that does not make it a 20 bit number, so long as you limit yourself to the lower two bits of that upper nibble you can still use hex to represent numbers that are not a multiple of 4 bits.  (yes companies that were very octal based in their assembly language had 9 bit bytes/registers, 18 or 36 bit addresses/registers and so on, pdp-11 being one, that is supported by gnu today, and is a little confusing to deal with using hex since nothing lines up).

Comment: assembly language or programming languages in general are specific to the tool not the target.  So what number bases you can use in a programming language to represent numbers and what syntax you use to create those values can and will vary from language to target.  for example $8,  8h, 0x8 and 8 are all ways to represent 8 in hexadecimal across different languages, tools and targets over time, that does not mean that you can use all of these for a specific tool (for a specific target or specific language).

Comment: the more interesting, and perhaps relevant question is more of will 0x8 represent 0x00000008 or 0xFFFFFFF8 in some random language.  What does the tool do to extend the value represented in the programming language to fit the space in the destination.  Try char x=0x80;  then printf("%X",x); in C.  And you get more than two nibbles printed.  but make x = 0x08 and you dont.  It makes perfect sense why (make it unsigned char x=0x80 and it now prints something different).

Comment: a fun one in good old x86 assembly is 0ah will give you 10 decimal but ah does not.